# Unable to download Library using cocoaPods

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I am new in swift programming . I  am trying to download libraries for the project . I have installed  cocoa pods : sudo gem install cocoa pods, created pod file with all libraries which I need : pod 'GoogleMaps'.  After pod install I got an error:

```
 Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

 - `GoogleMaps` required by `Podfile`
 - `GoogleMaps` required by `Podfile`
 - `GoogleMaps (= 2.3.1)` required by `Podfile.lock`

 Specs satisfying the `GoogleMaps, GoogleMaps (= 2.3.1)` dependency    
 were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

 [!] Automatically assigning platform ios with version 7.0 on target 
  Taxi for rider because no platform was specified. Please specify a 
 platform    for this target in your Podfile. See   
 `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

My pod file:

```
  # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your    
  project
  # platform :ios, '9.0'

  target 'Taxi for rider' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to     
  use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Taxi for rider
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'GooglePlacesAPI'
  pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'

  end
```

Comment: Could you show your podfile?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your podfile text with below text:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Taxi for rider' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!


 # Pods for Taxi for rider

  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'GooglePlacesAPI'
  pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
end
```

Below is wrong line in your code:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your    
project
```

Which should be:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
```

And you have added `pod 'GoogleMaps'` multiple times.

Comment: Thanks a lot yes it is quite simple . I have uncommented and it works now

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as correct if that works. @GermanPodorognik

Answer (score 0):

You should define a platform for your project in your Podfile. Append this to the beginning of your Podfile:

```
platform :<ios, macos, tvos etc.>, '<version of the OS>'
```

Example:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

Comment: Yes I did it actually

Comment: You did not uncomment the line. Remove `#` from the beginning of it.

Answer (score 0):

Step Of Install Cocoa Pods.

**Step 1** - Close your Xcode project which you install pod file. and Open terminal.

**Step 2** - type **cd**  command and Drag your project path.

[image: dra your project path]

**Step 3**  - press Enter and type **pod init** conmmand then open your project folder, now you can see pod file

[image: type pod init]

[image: you can see pod file in red mark open it]

**Step 4** - open pod file and write pod name which you install

[image: Enter pod name and save]

**Step 5** - save and close pod file and again open terminal and write **pod install** command and wait few minutes to install pod

[image]

After install pod go to your project folder and open .work space file and enjoy.

[image: selected file is workspace file]

now pod is installed enjoy and used.